# How do I remove all labels from a YARN Node?

Tags: hadoop-yarn

### YARN version

Apache Hadoop 3.1.2

### Scheduler

Capacity Scheduler

### Labels

highpriority, elastic

### Node Label assignment

- node1 [default]
- node2 [default]
- node3 [default]
- node4 highpriority
- node5 highpriority
- node6 highpriority
- node7 elastic
- node8 elastic

### What I do

I use this command to replace node1, node2 and node3 to label highpriority:

```bash
yarn rmadmin -replaceLabelsOnNode "node1=highpriority node2=highpriority node3=highpriority" -failOnUnknownNodes
```

This takes effect immediately. Then I submit some apps and they goes to this label as the queue assignment defines. Good.

However ~
After some time, when I decide to get node1, node2 and node3 back to normal [default], I tried:

```bash
yarn rmadmin -replaceLabelsOnNode "node1= node2= node3=" -failOnUnknownNodes
```

Yet, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

After some diggings and attempts, what I find was:

Run this:

```bash
yarn rmadmin -replaceLabelsOnNode "node1=, node2=, node3=," -failOnUnknownNodes
```

The labels assigned to those nodes are removed.
That is, to simply add the label delimiter (,) does the job.

: ]